# to get count in each bin

Tags: sql, count, grouping

Is there a way to simplify this SQL query?

```
SELECT
count(case when R1 >= 0 AND R1 < 5 AND (M1/102) >= 0 AND (M1/102) < 4 THEN 1 END) AS BIN0_1,
count(case when R1 >= 0 AND R1 < 5 AND (M1/102) >= 4 AND (M1/102) < 8 THEN 1 END) AS BIN0_2,
count(case when R1 >= 0 AND R1 < 5 AND (M1/102) >= 8 AND (M1/102) < 12 THEN 1 END) AS BIN0_3,
count(case when R1 >= 0 AND R1 < 5 AND (M1/102) >= 12 AND (M1/102) < 16 THEN 1 END) AS BIN0_4,
count(case when R1 >= 0 AND R1 < 5 AND (M1/102) >= 16 AND (M1/102) < 245 THEN 1 END) AS BIN0_5,
count(case when R1 >= 5 AND R1 < 15 AND (M1/102) >= 0 AND (M1/102) < 4 THEN 1 END) AS BIN5_1,
count(case when R1 >= 5 AND R1 < 15 AND (M1/102) >= 4 AND (M1/102) < 8 THEN 1 END) AS BIN5_2,
count(case when R1 >= 5 AND R1 < 15 AND (M1/102) >= 8 AND (M1/102) < 12 THEN 1 END) AS BIN5_3,
count(case when R1 >= 5 AND R1 < 15 AND (M1/102) >= 12 AND (M1/102) < 16 THEN 1 END) AS BIN5_4,
count(case when R1 >= 5 AND R1 < 15 AND (M1/102) >= 16 AND (M1/102) < 20 THEN 1 END) AS BIN5_5,
count(case when R1 >= 5 AND R1 < 15 AND (M1/102) >= 20 AND (M1/102) < 245 THEN 1 END) AS BIN5_6,
count(case when R1 >= 15 AND R1 < 30 AND (M1/102) >= 0 AND (M1/102) < 4 THEN 1 END) AS BIN15_1,
count(case when R1 >= 15 AND R1 < 30 AND (M1/102) >= 4 AND (M1/102) < 8 THEN 1 END) AS BIN15_2,
count(case when R1 >= 15 AND R1 < 30 AND (M1/102) >= 8 AND (M1/102) < 12 THEN 1 END) AS BIN15_3,
count(case when R1 >= 15 AND R1 < 30 AND (M1/102) >= 12 AND (M1/102) < 16 THEN 1 END) AS BIN15_4,
count(case when R1 >= 15 AND R1 < 30 AND (M1/102) >= 16 AND (M1/102) < 20 THEN 1 END) AS BIN15_5,
count(case when R1 >= 15 AND R1 < 30 AND (M1/102) >= 20 AND (M1/102) < 245 THEN 1 END) AS BIN15_6

FROM MyTable
WHERE U1 = 'pmd'
AND day >= '2014-01-01'
```

The table has:

- 200k rows and 100 columns with column R1 (numeric values between 0 - 600)
- Column M1 (numeric values between 1 - 25000)

The result should be a row (or column) of counts (occurrences) in each bin.

For example, `BIN0_1` should have the # of occurrences when:

- `0<R1<5` and    `0 < M1/102 < 4`.

The above query works but since there are many more similar rows in the code (R1 between 30 and 45, 45 and 60, 60 and 120, etc.), wondering if there's an easier way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `BETWEEN` instead of separate `>=` and `<` tests.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Some of them have built-in pivot methods that may help simplify this.

Comment: @Barmar, using Netezza

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the comparisons with flags.  That way you don't have to repeat them:

```
SELECT (r1_0_5 * m1_0_4) as bin_01
FROM (SELECT (case when R1 >= 0 AND R1 < 5 then 1 else 0 end) as r1_0_5,
             (case when R1 >= 5 AND R1 < 15 then 1 else 0 end) as r1_5_15,
             (case when R1 >= 15 AND R1 < 30 then 1 else 0 end) as r1_15_30,
             (case when (M1/102) >= 0 AND (M1/102) < 4 then 1 else 0 end) as m1_0_4,
             . . .   
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE U1 = 'pmd' AND day >= '2014-01-01'
     ) t;
```

Or, you could put the results on different rows in the output:

```
SELECT r_bin, m_bin, count(*)
FROM (SELECT (case when R1 >= 0 AND R1 < 5 then '0_5',
                   when R1 >= 5 AND R1 < 15 then '5_15',
                   when R1 >= 15 AND R1 < 30 then '15_30'
              end) as r_bin,
             (case when (M1/102) >= 0 AND (M1/102) < 4 then '0_4'
                   . . .
              end) as m_bin   
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE U1 = 'pmd' AND day >= '2014-01-01'
     ) t
group by r_bin, m_bin;
```